# Why does SQL Server 2012 create single user databases by default?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

When I create a database - it creates it as (single user):

1. Why is that my default? Do I have it in my settings?
2. How do I change an existing database from single to multi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you create a new database, what you get is a copy of the [`model`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx) database, so it sounds like your `model` database has been set to single user.

> When a `CREATE DATABASE` statement is issued, the first part of the database is created by copying in the contents of the **model** database. The rest of the new database is then filled with empty pages.
>
> If you modify the **model** database, all databases created afterward will inherit those changes. For example, you could set permissions or *database options*, or add objects such as tables, functions, or stored procedures.

(*My emphasis*)

To change a database back to concurrent usage, [run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx):

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbName> set multi_user
```

Replacing `<dbName>` with the name of the database to change.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

By default, it will be in a multi-user mode.

Under certain circumstances, you may have to start an instance of SQL Server in single-user mode by using the startup option `-m`. For example, you may want to change server configuration options or recover a damaged master database or other system database. Both actions require starting an instance of SQL Server in single-user mode.

To change the database from multi-user to single user:

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST_DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

To change the database from single-user to multi user:

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST_DB SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```